# how do I capture the first non-zero integer from the back of an integer?

Tags: python, loops, integer

```
def last_digit(n):
    factorials = []
    for i in range(1,n + 1):
        i = str(i)
        i = i[::-1]
        for j in i:
            if j != 0:
                factorials.append(j)
                break
```

For each integer from 1 to some integer n, I am trying to capture the 'first' non-zero integer from the back of each integer.

For example, if we had 18600, then the integer I want is 6.

When I run the above code on paper it works, however when I run it on my IDE, it is not correct, in particular for '10', it captures the zero, but what I thought is happening is I reverse it so it becomes '01'; then the inner for loop will capture the first non-zero.

Comment: Once you convert the integer to a string, you can use `rstrip('0')` to strip away the rightmost zeros. Then the last character will be non-zero.

Comment: the problem is that 'j' is a string so you should do this: if j != '0':

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve this you should first convert the integer 'n' to a string and iterate through it in the reverse order.
Below is the code for demonstrating this.

```
  def last_digit(n): 
    n=str(n)
    rev=n[::-1] # Reversing the string 'n'
    for i in rev:
        if i!='0' :
            print(i)
            break
```

Answer (score -1):

You can first convert the number to string and then do this:

```
def last_digit(n):
    factorials = []
    for i in range(1,n + 1):
        i = str(i)
        factorials.append(i.strip('0')[-1])
    return factorials
```

`strip` function will remove all the zeros from beginning and end if the string and then using index -1 you can get the last character.